# Make my iCloud @me.com email my primary Apple ID

Tags: ios, icloud, mobileme, apple-id

Before iCloud began operation I used a gmail email for my Apple ID. With the advent of iCloud I have begun using my iCloud email for everything. The one thing that frustrates me is that Apple does not allow me to change my Apple ID to be my @me.com address.

The Apple ID page suggests making my @me.com address my ID, but every time I click it, it is not allowed. If I try to force it to change I get the message: "You cannot create an Apple ID using a MobileMe account. If this is your email address, it is also your Apple ID." This is obviously a remnant of MobileMe. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I am dealing with the exact same thing. I contacted customer support and they told me the @me address I created under my iCloud account (it's a Gmail name) is a different entity. She said it would "never" be allowed as my Apple ID. It seems like such a no brainer deal to change that but apple is being garbage about it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the @me address to your existing apple Id?

You should then be able to verify the address and set as primary address

Once it's added, you should jut be able to use it as your Apple id login

Edit: it seems the My Apple Id page has changed recently, you can no longer set an email address as a primary email address and as your AppleID.

[Apple Knowledge Base article from October 2011](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE40) shows hows to do this but this ability is not present in the current live My Apple ID page.

It is still the case however that @me.com email addresses are valid aliases for your AppleId and you can log in to any service with one instead of your primary.

Comment: Yes, it is verified as a secondary email. I can sign in using it, but I would prefer to not see my gmail account on iTunes, iOS and everywhere else. I would really like to completely stop using that GMail account.

Comment: then use the new email address as your itunes account, it will map to the same Apple ID so will be no issues.

Comment: The linked Knowledge Base article has been amended in February to reflect the apparent change in My Apple Id page. It now says:
*Note:* Some Apple IDs, like those ending in /@mac.com or /@me.com, can't be changed.